# How do you reference bindings multiple times within a Pakyow view?

Tags: pakyow

## The Background

I'm working on a view where I would like to use data from the same object in multiple places, but is interrupted by data from other objects. Think of a form letter that needs to know about a person, a company and an event, and references are spread throughout the letter.

I'm running Pakyow 0.9.1 on Thin web server.

## What I've Done

The binding worked with only the later reference. I added one before, and it worked. Only one is bound at a time. I added `pp` in each binding and only the first hits the console.

## The View

`<strong data-scope="account" data-prop="name">name</strong>`

...

`<a href="#" data-scope="token" data-prop="url">Click here</a>`

...

`<strong data-scope="account" data-prop="name">name</strong>`

Comment: Can you share the backend binding code?

Comment: `binding(:name) do
      pp "in :name"
      bindable.name
end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To directly answer your question, you'd need to call bind twice on account:

```
view.scope(:account)[0].bind(account)
view.scope(:account)[1].bind(account)
```

In this case though it might be helpful to abstract away the concepts of `account` and `token` and instead have a single scope called `mail_vars` or something to that affect. Then, just combine your data into a single data structure and bind it to the view.

Lots of ways to do this, hope it helps!

Comment: Hmm. I'm going with the first solution, but the separate scope intrigues me, especially if I could do it without repeating myself.